# Java: Programming stations and the time it takes to move from 1 station to the other (need idea's)

Tags: java, data-structures, architecture

one of my classes of the program I'm making needs to hold a list of stations and also the time it takes to move from one station to another.

My problem:

I want to make sure I don't mess up the timings and want to link them in some way to the 2 stations.
Example:

If I have 4 stations (station1 ... station4) and I have the time it takes between each pair of stations (let's say 5, 10, 15 minutes).

How can I store this information best ? Which collection do I use ?
I though of using a hashmap but the problem is I would have to make a key consist of 2 stations, is this the best way ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: **KISS**  What's wrong with a 2D array indexed such that `travel_time[a][b]` is the time to travel from `a` to `b` ?

Comment: What are your conditions in terms of design? since this does look like a exam or a homework task, what are your must haves, what do you need to use and where can you differ in terms of designing

Comment: Exactly, as High Performance Mark said, even if not all the stations are directly connected, 2D array seems like the best idea. The only exception can occur if you end up with the sparse matrix because connections are so rare, but from what you said it's unlikely.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you sollution if to index a 2D array using the 2 stations and the value is the travel time ?

Comment: Yes, Agnaroc, that's what I mean.  And if you want to be sophisticated about it think of the array as *an adjacency matrix with weights representing travel times*.  Search around for the term *adjacency matrix*, you'll get the idea.

Comment: How about `Map<String, Map<String, Double>>` which means `Map<fromStation, Map<toStation, minutes>>`?

Comment: @up why would you prefer it over array? HashMap is slower, requires more memory, and you need a separate object for each connection.

Comment: @pnadczuk `HashMap` will require less memory in case of sparse matrix (e. g. 1000 stations and 10000 connections--in array 99% of values will be "-1").

Comment: @Sasha That's true, in case of a sparse matrix it would be more efficient to use Object Oriented approach :). But from the question, I recon that it is not sparse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
int nStations = ...;
int[][] travelTime = new int[nStations][nStations];
for (int i = 0; i < nStations; i++) {
    travelTime[i][i] = 0; //distance from the station to itself
                          //is equal to zero, because you are already there 
}
```

then you have to assign values like this

```
travelTime[source][destination] = ...; //distance from station x to station y
```

and simply use it later on :).

if there is no direct connection between stations, you can make mark it by

```
travelTime[x][z] = -1; //if negative value - no direct connection.
```

---

**Moreover** if you want to use **String** objects **as station names**, you of course can
Just create a

```
HashMap<String, Integer> nameToIndex = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

Of course you have to initialize values, i.e.

```
nameToIndex.put("New York", 0);
nameToIndex.put("Chicago", 1);
```

Then if you want to get the travel time between New York and Chicago, simply use

```
travelTime[nameToIndex.get("New York")][nameToIndex.get("Chicago")];
```

---

**Why Arrays**

I also want to explain why is it better in my opinion to use 2d array than a HashMap of objects.
If you plan to use this program to check distances between 10 stations, you won't see any difference. However, if this number increases to, let's say, 10000, the performance gain will be substantial (You can measure it yourself).

I would also argue that this solution would be easier to debug in case of any problems, since it is very straightforward. On the other hand, if you create a separate object for each connection, you end up with huge collections that are really hard to see through.

One problem you can encounter occurs when the stations change. Because you have to change indexes of the whole array in order to reflect this change, it is more difficult than, say, remove an object from the collection. But since stations do not change very often, it is more important to focus on performance in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

You key can consist of 2 objects, why this is a problem for you?

```
public final class Pair<T> {
    public final T o1, o2;

    public Pair(T o1, T o2) {
        this.o1 = Objects.requireNonNull(o1);
        this.o2 = Objects.requireNonNull(o2);
    }

    // make hashCode symmetric
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
       return o1.hashCode() + o2.hashCode();
    }

    // make equals also symmetric
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if (other == this) return true;
        if (other == null || !other.getType().equals(getType())) return false;
        T o = (T) other;
        return (o1.equals(o.o1) && o2.equals(o.o2)) || (o2.equals(o.o1) && o1.equals(o.o2));
    }
}
```

Then you can use `HashMap`:

```
Map<Pair<Station>, Double> timings = new HashMap<>();
timings.put(new Pair(station1, station2), 5.0);
timings.put(new Pair(station1, station3), 10.0);
//....
```

Then, to get timing between two stations, use:

```
Double t  = timings.get(new Pair(station1, station2));
if (t != null) {
    // stations are connected
}
```

or, with the same result,

```
Double t1 = timings.get(new Pair(station2, station1));
```

This approach is not as fast as adjacency array, but it has own advantages: 1) you don't need to enumerate stations or to map `Station` objects to array indices, 2) in case of [sparse graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix) it wins in space consumption.

Comment: `if (!(other instanceof T)) return false;` comparing `getType()` is better for non-final classes. `if (other==null || !other.getType().equals(getType())) return false;`

Comment: Hope you get why: Consider `public class Tripple<T> extends Pair<T> { T o3 }` then: `new Tripple(1,2,3).equals(new Pair(1,2)) == false` good, but `new Pair(1,2).equals(new Tripple(1,2,3)) == true` bad.

Comment: @weston I just simply made it final. Thanks. Cannot imagine when a triple is supposed to be equal to pair.

Comment: Yes exactly. but most importantly, you cannot ensure preservation of symmetry, thus the equality contract is broken. `final` is fine with `instanceof`, but prob best to stick to `getType` incase you remove `final` at a later point.

Comment: @weston yes, I see it now. I appreciate your explanation.

Comment: This is a gross over-design for the problem as stated.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark this is your opinion, I don't think so. In update, I provide advantages of this approach.